# coin toss p value

Tags: p-value

When you toss a coin you get 8 heads and 2 tails. How would you analyze whether a coin is fair? What is the p-value?

The p-value is easy to calculate and it is 56/1024. However I couldn't solve the second part.

In addition, more coins are added to this experiment. Now you have 10 coins. You toss each coin 10 times (100 tosses in total) and observe results. Would you modify your approach to the the way you test the fairness of coins?

Comment: (A) Your p-value is too small: you need a two-sided test for this hypothesis.  (B) For the second part, what hypothesis do you wish to test?  Several that come to mind are (1) whether all coins are fair, (2) whether at least one coin is fair, (3) whether the coins are fair on average, (4) whether a majority are fair.

Comment: @PA6OTA $56 = \binom{10}{2}+\binom{10}{1}+\binom{10}{0}$ is the result of a one-tailed test.